# ElasticSearch query with conditions on element of a list in a document

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to write a query on a document that looks like his

```
      {
          "chargeElement": "user",
          "chargeType": "AUTO_SCALING",
          "cycle": {
            "count": 1,
            "interval": "MONTH",
            "name": "MONTHLY"
          },
          "tiers": [
            {
              "ceiling": 250,
              "floor": 101,
              "unitAmount": 440
            },
            {
              "ceiling": 15000,
              "floor": 10001,
              "unitAmount": 230
            },
            {
              "ceiling": 100,
              "flatAmount": 4750,
              "floor": 11,
              "unitAmount": 575
            },
            {
              "ceiling": 10,
              "flatAmount": 1000,
              "floor": 1
            }]
}
```

I would like to get all the documents for which for the tier item with tiers.floor = 1 flatAmount is anything more than 0. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Yes, its possible. The tiers is nested type?

Comment: I had marked them as object type but I can put in a request to change the type to nested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the field tiers is nested type you can use Nested Query. The query below get documents with items with tiers.floor = 1 and flatAmount > 0.

This way the match is because of the item: {"ceiling": 10, "flatAmount": 1000, "floor": 1 }.

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "inner_hits": {}, 
      "path": "tiers",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "term": {
                "tiers.floor": {
                  "value": 1
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "tiers.flatAmount": {
                  "gt": 0
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```